# Transforming a list of alists into a different list of alists based on values

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, reduce

I want to transform this list of alists:

```
(setq terms '((("name" . "t1c1")
               ("taxonomy" . "category"))
              (("name" . "t1c2")
               ("taxonomy" . "category"))
              (("name" . "t1k1")
               ("taxonomy" . "post_tag"))
              (("name" . "t1k2")
               ("taxonomy" . "post_tag"))
              (("name" . "t1k3")
               ("taxonomy" . "post_tag"))))
```

into this other list of alists:

```
(("category" "t1c1" "t1c2")
 ("post_tag" "t1k1" "t1k2" "t1k3"))
```

I have come up with:

```
(reduce
 '(lambda (lists term)
    (let* ((name (cdr (assoc "name" term)))
           (taxonomy (cdr (assoc "taxonomy" term)))
           (existing (assoc taxonomy lists)))
      (if existing
          (progn
            (setcdr existing (sort (cons name (cdr existing)) 'string<)))
        (push (list taxonomy name) lists)))
    lists)
 terms
 :initial-value nil)
```

which seems inelegant---the use of let* and the if statement both seem like potential code smells.

I would appreciate any examples of better ways to do this in elisp---where better might mean more purely functional, better use of built-in functions to represent certain operations, etc.

Oh, and I would like to have the contents of the resulting alists sorted---it makes it easier for me to test the output.

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant that comes to mind is to use `(loop ...)` macro. One might argue it's not elisp-y enough, but I think it's conciseness and expressiveness beats purity:

```lisp
(loop
 with result = '()
 for term in terms
 for name = (aget term "name")
 for taxonomy = (aget term "taxonomy")
 do (aput 'result taxonomy
          (sort (cons name (aget result taxonomy)) 'string<))
 finally return result)
```

Comment: So, I am fairly new to lisp, so I may be off-base---but it seems that you've really just implemented reduce using loop, and the conciseness is actually coming from using aput/aget, where I'm doing my alist manipulation without using assoc.el (which is declared obsolete as of Emacs 24.3).

Comment: Also, I'm new enough to lisp that doing it without a ton of parens seems...wrong. ;)

Comment: That's fine :) Everyone finds something special for them about lisps, I personally like the -- arguably -- perfect balance between functional & imperative code. The parentheses that make the code itself an AST are just cherry on the top and allow things like paredit which I sorely miss when doing python and C/C++.

As for `assoc.el` deprecation, yeah, I should've suspected something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

> I would appreciate any examples of better ways to do this in
>   elisp---where better might mean more purely functional, better use of
>   built-in functions to represent certain operations, etc.

Maybe something like this (assumes `cl-lib` is loaded):

```
(cl-flet ((step (lists term)
            (let ((name (aget term "name"))
                  (taxonomy (aget term "taxonomy")))
              (cl-acons taxonomy
                        (sort (cons name (aget lists taxonomy)) #'string<)
                        (cl-remove taxonomy lists :key #'car :test #'equal)))))
  (reduce #'step dhl-terms :initial-value nil))
```

It will be less efficient than your solution, since "more purely functional" also means no use of `setcdr` – it will cons the new entries, and make one more pass to remove the old ones.

Comment: Yeah, not using setcdr shortens it---no need to test for existence---but also makes it less efficient.

Comment: Yes. If you're concerned about performance, you could improve it by just consing to the front of the resultig alist, and deleting the unneeded entries as a final step using `cl-remove-duplicates` with `:from-end t`. (The sorting could be done after that, too.) But whether this actually makes a difference depends on your use case.

Comment: In fact, in reviewing the two answers, that very realization had just dawned on me: since I just want to end up with an alist I can query for the two keys I know in advance, I can just cons the updated items to the front of the alist, and my query will only see the most-recent, and thus most-complete, version of each list.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the advantages of using alists. (It didn't match your example output, so I did it as is and kept it relatively close to your original code.)

Comment: By the way: I didn't know that `aget` &c were obsolete, as you stated in your comment to immerrr's answer. You could still save a few chars by using `assoc-default` without its optional arguments.

Comment: Well, they've been "obsolete" for what, a week?  I think you're excused on that count.

As for the rest, well, I over-specified things, and you were working toward what had been asked.